# Undiagnosable Myopia

Tags: eye

In short, I can't see. I'm having no problems seeing up close, but once it gets close to 9-10 inches away from my eyes, everything gets blurry. I have been to 4 eye doctors (2 opthamologists, 2 optometrists), and none have been able to find any substantial refractive error, even with the use of an autorefractor. I know it doesn't make much sense, but it's getting a bit difficult to function with this much unaccommodated myopia. As eye doctors are unable to find the cause of this, what course of action should I take?

Comment: I'm confused - are you saying your vision for objects more than 10 inches away is blurred, but you are still "passing" the vision tests with no result?

Answer (score -3):

When small print is closer than ten inches (depends upon severity) to your eyes and it becomes blurrier, that is [presbyopia](http://eyewiki.aao.org/Presbyopia), not myopia. Explore the the link to the American Academy of Ophthalmology.   Presbyopia is age related, starting about 35 - 40 years old.

Try some "reading glasses", not normal glasses.  Reading glasses can be purchased at most pharmacies without a prescription or  dollar stores.  Even if there is some other problem, reading glasses are great for reading very small print such as on electronic circuit boards and but allow your eyes to relax at the same time.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.This site requires [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/). We appreciate the fact that this is a burden; consider how appreciated sources on answers to your own potential questions would be. Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about the site. Also, you might want to re-read the OP's description. I read it as myopia. He sees up close, but as he moves away, it gets blurry.